# boost socket vs stream_socket endpoint in ctor vs connect method

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

There is `boost::basic_socket` and `boost::basic_stream_socket`; both have constructor that accepts `const endpoint_type & endpoint` and [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload3.html) says

> An endpoint on the local machine to which the stream socket will be bound.

yet there is a `connect` method, where the [doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect/overload1.html) says

> peer_endpoint -- The remote endpoint to which the socket will be connected.

How does it work, what's what? When I'm writing a client, I'd create a socket, not providing endpoint in ctor, then call connect and then do read/write. And when writing a server, I'd use the ctor endpoint and not be calling connect? And what's the difference between normal socket and stream socket?

Comment: What do you mean by a normal socket? `basic_stream_socket` is used for the TCP socket, while `basic_datagram_socket` is used for the UDP socket. For the other questions you should start with the [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html) which gives the examples of the [client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html) and the [server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html).

Comment: @karastojko: "normal socket" was referring to `boost::basic_socket` while there's `boost::basic_stream_socket`.

Comment: As [stated](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html), `basic_socket` is a kind of abstract class for both TCP and UDP. `basic_stream_socket` is meant for the TCP and `basic_datagram_socket` is meant for the UDP type of sockets. They inherit from `basic_socket` class for the more specific features of the TCP/UDP protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ctor the endpoint is to be used with `bind()` which binds the socket to a an address and a port in the local machine

In connect the endpoint represents the remote address and port you are connection to

In general any socket needs to be bound before using it with `accept()` or `connect()` or any send/recv method . But when you use `connect()` syscall the system checks if the socket is already bound and if not it binds it for you so it's better when using socket as a client to connect to server to let the os bind the socket for you, there is an exception which is `ConnectEx` on windows as it doesn't bind the socket automatically so you are responsible to bind it yourself.

For servers the things are different because you bind the acceptor socket to the local address and port clients are connecting to so the os can't deduce which address or port you wish to receive connections on in order to bind the socket for you , as a result you have to explicitly call `bind()` with the your chosen address and port

Comment: so to summarize, when I want to implement a client, I'll use a ctor without socket, and then I'll call connect
and when to implement a server, I'll use a ctor with a socket, it will be bound for me, and I can start accepting clients on it -- never calling connect. Am I right?

Comment: For client socket use connect without a local address and port (without bind , don't need to specify an endpoint in the ctor) , and for server use accept with bind (use an endpoint in the ctor or call bind before accept)